# Joomla Custom-Component Select Field with Editor

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, editor, dropdown

I'm trying to make a dropdown box from my table (`#__projectinfo`) where I can choose, for example, an article and show in an editor ready-to-use, update or save.

The objective is to choose an email body and send it to a user, the select box is to choose the email, but I need the ready-to-use editor.

e.g: like an article editor (see below image)

[image]

Comment: Hi Miguel - We read in your post that you are trying and that you have an objective, but we don't read what is the exact question you have... Please read the [help] and [help/on-topic] to get informed on how to participate in this site. Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not clear what the question is - not a specific question to a single specific problem is defined in this post.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit beyond scope of the SE but I would like to give you a direction.

You can create you own JFormField that can open a modal window. Joomla uses this technique in com_menu selecting com_content articles.

You can have a look at [JFormFieldModal_Article](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/b67cf1d309717878b70ae140085152412c6dd0b9/administrator/components/com_content/models/fields/modal/article.php), this should give you an example how the field could look like.

The second part is the editor window, you need a component where you can edit the table. In this component you can add a "modal" layout to the edit view. In com_content this can be found at [view/article/tmpl/modal.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/b67cf1d309717878b70ae140085152412c6dd0b9/administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/modal.php)

The complete task is not trivial and you need some knowledge in creating Joomla! components.